# numpy generate random elements within triangle

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to generate random points within a triangle based on the points `(0, 0) (0, 1), (1, 0.5)`. I figure the easiest way to do this is to generate the points within the `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)` square using numpy and then filter it to that triangle.

Here is the code that will generate the points within that square.

```
pts = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
```

However, I'm not sure how to filter the numpy array to only the points within that triangle.

Comment: What do you mean by "slice the numpy arrays"?  Where does an array come into this process?

Comment: If you filter, won't you have too few data points?

Comment: What distribution do you need for the points?  If you don't need uniform density, there are parametric ways to generate the points directly.

Comment: @Prune I should have noted that I generate the random points in a numpy array. Corrected.

Comment: @ScottHunter Exact number doesn't matter.

Comment: @Prune uniform is ideal

Comment: Generated *what* data?  You're asking us how to generate data, not what to do with data you've already generated.  Where is your code and result?  What part of the problem remains?

Comment: @Prune I've added some code, but I'm not sure what part of the question is unclear. I'm just trying to filter randomly generated points so that they all lay within a triangle defined by the specified points.

Comment: It looks like the hard part is [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-triangle-or-not/) . I think the question is not about generating random data, but about checking if it's inside a poligon

Comment: What's not clear is what you need solved: there are contradictions in your description..  Your text says that you want to know how to generate points within a given, bounded region.  Then you say that you already have the points.  You talk about slicing your array of points -- but I fail to see any organization within your code that will obtain the desired points by mere slicing.

Comment: @Ivan: that's a general solution from analytical algebra; I've used it myself.  This filtering -- if filtering is, indeed, the desired solution -- is a much simpler problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go for a filtering approach, you have to find a condition to check which points are inside the triangle. Then you can use numpys argwhere function to find the indices of all points that fullfill your condition:

```
pts = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
x_coord = pts[:, 0]
y_coord = pts[:, 1]


def _in_triangle(x, y):
# You might want to doublecheck if this condition is correct, I am sure there is a better way.
    return (((x <= 0.5) & (y <= 2*x)) | ((x <= 0.5) & (y <= 2-2*x))) & (0 <= x) & (x <= 1) & (0 <= y) & (y <= 1)


points_in_triangle = pts[np.argwhere(_in_triangle(x_coord, y_coord))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I had a mental block around this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try a multi-pronged answer for the unresolved contingencies:

If you don't need a uniform distribution, then simply generate the x-coord uniformly from [0, 1], then generate the y-coord from [0.5-((1-x)/2), 0.5+((1-x)/2)] (yes, you can simplify those expressions).  This makes each x-coordinate equally likely, and therefore favors points with fewer corresponding y-coordinates: points near the apex of your triangle will get chosen more often than those near the base.

You can correct this with the inverse transformation on your x-coordinate: square `x` before you choose y.

---

If you need to use the points you already generated, then you have no choice but to filter them in some fashion.  Half of them will be unsuitable, with those points randomly distributed through your array.  There is no way to slice the array to achieve that result.

EDIT CREDIT to Scott Hunter

However, you can filter and transform the unsuitable points: map them with a simple transformation from outside the triangle to inside.  Your triangle is bounded above by the lines

```
y = 2x
y = -2x + 2
```

A simple mapping is to reflect each point above these lines, across the midpoint of the line segment: either (0.25, 0.5) or (0.75, 0.5).  This is a simple equation: to reflect point `(x, y)` across point `(a, b)`, the reflection is `(2a-x, 2b-y)`.

Comment: "No choice" is a bit strong; as there is at least 1 one-to-one correspondence from each point outside the triangle to one inside which could be applied, thus avoiding the need for a filter.

Comment: How do you get a 1:1 correspondence?  The points are generated randomly, so the inside/outside populations are almost guaranteed to be other than 500-500.

Comment: 1:1 from any possible outside point to a distinct inside point.

Comment: I think I get it: Make the transformation on sets of the same size -- yeah, that's elegant.  You should write that up as a solution.  It's on the same time order as filtering, but you keep all of the points.